# Beginner guard ruby on rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

It might be a very stupid question but I was following an intro to rails tutorial and in there when you run the `guard` command , it shows :

```
Running all specs.
No examples found.

Finished in 0.000003 seconds
```

But in my computer it just shows the following and nothing as the tutorial shows.

```
20:01:17 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
20:01:17 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
20:01:17 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/Name/rails_testprojects/zone'
[1] guard(main)>
```

Again , I am totally new and trying to make my first ruby app !

The link of the tutorial I was watching ! Sorry for not providing it in my first edit !

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMcEgOPza8A

Comment: can you post the link to the tutorial? always give as much info as you can with your question so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Guard is a fantastic tool that tremendously helps with Test Driven Development (TDD), and I couldn't imagine coding without it, but that's besides the point.

It looks like the tutorial you are following is misleading you. The reason I believe this is that Guard will continually watch the locations given in the Guardfile, until you manually stop it. The first snippet you posted looks like the instructor just ran "rspec". if configured correctly, guard will run your rspec specs, which removes the need to manually run rspec every time you make a change.

Comment: thank you , i figured what guard will do but my question was a bit different. And no , in the first snippet , he runs guard command after running guard init rspec

Comment: Have you tried running guard followed by changing a spec or another file guard is watching? If guard is configured right, then the specs should run.

Comment: or just hit enter once in the guard console.